# Reverting root folder permission changes

Tags: directory, root, python3, ownership

I just use the answer of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980289/recursively-set-all-files-and-folders-to-777-from-this-list#) and now all the folders in root have different permissions and I can't use some programs like Chromium, terminal, etc.

```
for your_dir in dirs_to_modify:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(your_dir):
        for d in dirs:
            os.chmod(os.path.join(root, d), 777)
        for f in files:
            os.chmod(os.path.join(root, f), 777)
```

I just replaced `dirs_to_modify` with `/home/my_user/.hidden_folder`

And I execute the script as root using sudo.

I feel like I broke my Ubuntu OS. Help please.

Comment: Why did you need to run the chmod 777 in that link in the first place?

Comment: I was testing a python package made by myself that, in other things, created a hidden folder in /home/user. However, that hidden folder had only root permission due that I installed the package using sudo python3 setup.py install. So, I just wanted  to change the ownership recursively of the hidden folder.

Comment: If you specified the folder correctly, it should only have affected that hidden folder, and it should not have done any damage to the OS.  However, an error may have cause you to change filesystem-wide permissions (from the root directory).  If that is the case, reinstalling Ubuntu is going to be a simpler fix than any other fix available, as there is no practical way to recover filesystem permissions of your entire filesystem.

Comment: Note, there is no reason to use `sudo` to change file permissions within your home directory, in fact using `sudo` to do such a thing is a bad idea as it makes accidentally breaking things *outside* your home directory easier.